# Displaying Images Side-by-Side in Qt with Scrollbars

Tags: qt

I'm a Qt newbie. I want to display 2 images side-by-side using Qt. Using [Qt's Image Viewer Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.2/widgets-imageviewer.html), I want to add another *scrollable* image display, such that both images are displayed side-by-side.

The example code has this snippet for the ctor:

```
ImageViewer::ImageViewer()
{
   imageLabel = new QLabel;
   imageLabel->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
   imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
   imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);

   scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
   scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
   scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);
   setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
   ...
```

If I understand it correctly, I want to get `imageLabel` to be only half width of the screen while another QLabel is displayed on the other half.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this here should suffice:

```
// Left image
imageLabelLeft = new QLabel;
imageLabelLeft->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
imageLabelLeft->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
imageLabelLeft->setScaledContents(true);

scrollAreaLeft = new QScrollArea;
scrollAreaLeft->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
scrollAreaLeft->setWidget(imageLabelLeft);

// Right image
imageLabelRight = new QLabel;
imageLabelRight->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
imageLabelRight->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
imageLabelRight->setScaledContents(true);

scrollAreaRight = new QScrollArea;
scrollAreaRight->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
scrollAreaRight->setWidget(imageLabelRight);

// Do the layout
QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget;
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(centralWidget);
layout->addWidget(scrollAreaLeft);
layout->addWidget(scrollAreaRight);

setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
```

Comment: Great! It works. Just what I wanted. I guessed it had something to do with a QHBoxLayout and setCentralWidget(), but I didn't know how to assemble everything together. Thank Bjoern.